# Does anyone have a TextPad syn file for GSP?

Tags: groovy, syntax-highlighting, gsp, textpad

I am looking for a syntax hilighting file for Textpad which hilights the Groovy g namespace.  I have been trying to build one myself and can't quite figure out how to do it - or whether it is possible to have namespace based syntax hilighting in TextPad at all.

I have a great one for Groovy, but nothing yet for GSP.  Has anyone created one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically, GSP is almost identical to JSP. I know nothing about TextPad, but could you instruct it to use the JSP syn file for .jsp and .gsp files?

Comment: that's the obvious thing to do, but of course it leaves out all the GSP specific tags.  What I have done is copy a JSP and start hacking around with it for GSP.

Comment: But surely the GSP syntax file will highlight any tags in the format `<namespace:tag>` whether these are coming from the JSTL namespace or the Grails namespace? Do you mean than if you accidentally type `<g:eacg>` instead of `<g:each>` the syntax file would highlight the error?